# Obtener cuantos números se encuentran en una cadena de texto con JavaScript

Tags: javascript

```
contarNumero: (text) => {
//TODO: esta función debe retornar cúantos números se encuentran en el texto

let countNumber = 0;

const cadena = text.split('') ;
console.log(countNumber+cadena)

for(let i=0; i<(cadena.length); i++){
 
  if(isNaN(cadena[i])){
  countNumber = countNumber +1}}

return countNumber;
```

Comment: ¿No será `if (!isNaN(cadena[i]))`?...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

¿Qué tal?

Como ya te han comentado, lo correcto sería que la condición se cumpla cuando el valor evaluado **no** sea un valor no-numérico, es decir, que no se cumpla la condición `isNaN(valor)`, por lo que tendrías que plantearlo como `!isNaN(valor)` dado que la negación (`!condición`) invierte el resultado: si es verdadero (el valor no es un número), se convierte en falso, y viceversa.

Otra forma de hacerlo en menos pasos sería a través del uso de [expresiones regulares](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_expressions):

```js
const cadena = "A 1, b2;C3-d48";
console.log(`La cadena contiene ${cadena.match(/[0-9]/g).length} números`);
```

> RESULTADO: La cadena contiene 5 números

Hay otras maneras de obtener el resultado por medio del uso de expresiones regulares. Pero si aún no estás familiarizado con ellas, solo sigue el consejo que te han dado y obtendrás el resultado que esperas.

Un saludo

Comment: muchas gracias me funciono! ;)

Comment: Gracias @DjCrazy por la edición. Había olvidado que se puede colocar ese *snippet* aquí.